# Why onclick doesn't trigger the function to reload page?

Tags: javascript, ruby, haml

I have this in one of the views but it doesn't seem to reload the page every 10 seconds after the button is clicked even though I bind the function to it.

```
  %footer.modal__footer
    %ul.modal__list
      %li.modal__list-item
        = submit_tag t('.start'), class: 'btn btn-success', id: 'AnalysisStart', :onClick=> 'refreshPage()'


:javascript
    function refreshPage(){
       window.setTimeout(function(){ document.location.reload(true); }, 10000);
  }
```

can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong? Or do I have any other way to achieve this?

Can one also interpolate js and ruby like this:

```
:javascript
-if document.analyses.ready.any?
    window.setTimeout(function(){ document.location.reload(true); }, 10000);
```

because something like this would solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your HAML code seems to be ok.

If you want your page to refresh after X seconds, you could simply use JavaScript:

```
const refreshAfter = (ms) => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
    document.location.reload(true)
  }, ms)
}

const onload = () => {
  refreshAfter(10000);
}

window.onload = onload;
```

This means that after the page `onload` event, a timer will wait for 10 seconds before refreshing the page by calling the `refreshAfter` function. Then, the page will refresh and a new page refresh will happen after 10 seconds.

If you want to trigger this function via the `onclick` button event, you can just directly call the `refreshAfter` function.

If you want to wait for a server side analysis to end before refreshing the page, maybe you should use JavaScript Ajax calls to achieve this, or WebSockets.

Comment: thank you for your answer. The problem lies exactly there, when I directly call the function via onclick button event. It doesn't seem to work as it should because the page keeps reloading even when the button is not clicked yet. I tried ajax calls but somehow didn't manage to get it work, therefore I'm trying this other rather more straightforward solution.